# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio trouble with permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-permissions, ssms

Please find all the files I'm refering to at this link:
http://whyisthisinmyfood.com/sql/

I have installed a new copy of "SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express (x86)" on two Windows 7 computers. The SAME install file for both computers. Installed the same way. (as far as I know, I chose the same options)
One at home and one at work.

The one at home seems to work perfectly I "Execute" this file (ITD132-Inventory Initial with data.sql) and it works fine. When I "Execute" it at work I get:

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>   ..and a bunch of stuff after that which is caused because the database was not created in the first place.

I have compared the permissions on both computers.
see these files:
home computer : non-networked.jpg
work computer: work-networked.jpg

I read in one post that to create new Logins one must be logged in as the Administrator.  I log into the Server Managment studio with my windows credentials and I am the Local Admin for my work computer and I have not been able to find any other place to log in as an administrator for this SQL Server Management Studio (so clearly I'm not sure whats meant by that)

At this point I think my problem is that I need to create a user who is not just the "BUILTIN\User" (because this login does not have permissions) with permissions.

But I have no idea how to login as an administrator to create this user role.

Please forgive me if these are obvious answers as I am just starting with this MS Management studio and am not very familiar with T-SQL.

Thanks,
Diana

Comment: This has nothing to do with Management Studio, it's the rights of the user you are using to connect to the SQL Server database engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you install SQL Server, you get asked during installation process which user or user group should have the Admin-Privileges. If your computer is part of a domain and you login locally, things might get complicated.

The easiest (but not safest way) to login as a "superuser" if to enable the "sa" user. 
this is one user that logs on with a password (not integrated logon) and has all the juice to run every script possible :-) By default it's disabled - googling I found a easy how-to enable it:

http://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/

Comment: Well, technically, if you installed using Windows auth only, it's not the sa account that's disabled, it's SQL authentication period.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct that you need to create another user with enough permission. Generally logging in with "integrated security" using your Windows credentials should have enough permissions (assuming the same user is the user that installed SQL Server). If not, you have better luck logging in as the SQL Server user "sa" (system administrator) which should have full permission. Do you know the "sa" password?

Note: the security mode for SQL Server can be set to "Only integrated security with Windows users", "SQL Server security" or "both". The "sa" account will only work if the SQL Server security is enabled. You may be able to access these settings using your BuiltIn\User account.

Comment: Actually in modern versions of SQL Server, having installed the engine is not enough, you also have to add that user to the group of SQL admins during setup. Also, there are only two settings: "Windows and SQL auth" or "Windows auth only." You can't have *just* SQL auth as your answer implies.